# How to force systeminfo output to english to parse it using Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have this simple string of code:

```
    $TotalMemory = (systeminfo | Select-String 'Total Physical Memory:').ToString().Split(':')[1].Trim()
    $TotalMemory = $TotalMemory -replace (",", "")
    $TotalMemory = $TotalMemory -replace ("MB", "")
    $TotalMemory | Set-Content ".\build\txt\ram.txt"
```

Which gathers RAM. Works fine. The issue is that I have a user that uses a Russian version of Windows, which the output is in Russian. Is there a way I can force, just for that command, the output of `systeminfo` to english, so it can be parsed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least within the same windows version the header count of systeminfo should be the same.

So using the `/FO csv` and `/NH` options you can force output in csv format without headers and supply the English version or numbered columns i.e.

Windows 10 English vs. Col#, German

```
$SystemInfoHeadersEn = (
    "Host Name",#                 Col0  Hostname
    "OS Name",#                   Col1  Betriebssystemname
    "OS Version",#                Col2  Betriebssystemversion
    "OS Manufacturer",#           Col3  Betriebssystemhersteller
    "OS Configuration",#          Col4  Betriebssystemkonfiguration
    "OS Build Type",#             Col5  Betriebssystem-Buildtyp
    "Registered Owner",#          Col6  Registrierter Benutzer
    "Registered Organization",#   Col7  Registrierte Organisation
    "Product ID",#                Col8  Produkt-ID
    "Original Install Date",#     Col9  Ursprüngliches Installationsdatum
    "System Boot Time",#          Col10 Systemstartzeit
    "System Manufacturer",#       Col11 Systemhersteller
    "System Model",#              Col12 Systemmodell
    "System Type",#               Col13 Systemtyp
    "Processor(s)",#              Col14 Prozessor(en)
    "BIOS Version",#              Col15 BIOS-Version
    "Windows Directory",#         Col16 Windows-Verzeichnis
    "System Directory",#          Col17 System-Verzeichnis
    "Boot Device",#               Col18 Startgerät
    "System Locale",#             Col19 Systemgebietsschema
    "Input Locale",#              Col20 Eingabegebietsschema
    "Time Zone",#                 Col21 Zeitzone
    "Total Physical Memory",#     Col22 Gesamter physischer Speicher
    "Available Physical Memory",# Col23 Verfügbarer physischer Speicher
    "Virtual Memory: Max Size",#  Col24 Virtueller Arbeitsspeicher: Maximale Größe
    "Virtual Memory: Available",# Col25 Virtueller Arbeitsspeicher: Verfügbar
    "Virtual Memory: In Use",#    Col26 Virtueller Arbeitsspeicher: Zurzeit verwendet
    "Page File Location(s)",#     Col27 Auslagerungsdateipfad(e)
    "Domain",#                    Col28 Domäne
    "Logon Server",#              Col29 Anmeldeserver
    "Hotfix(s)",#                 Col30 Hotfix(es)
    "Network Card(s)",#           Col31 Netzwerkkarte(n)
    "Hyper-V Requirements"#       Col32 Anforderungen für Hyper-V
)
```

That returns the information in an object, but still has localized/user settings dependent values (decimal point/comma, date format)

```
> $SystemInfo = systeminfo.exe /FO csv /NH |ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $SystemInfoHeadersEn
> $systeminfo.'Total Physical Memory'
16.349 MB
```

Or

```
> $SystemInfo = systeminfo.exe /FO csv /NH |ConvertFrom-Csv -Header (0..32|%{"Col$_"})
> $systeminfo.col22
16.349 MB
```

Comment: I never thought to use column number rather than the actual name of the item. duh me.

Answer (score 1):

i do not know how to set the language for SysInfo, but there are other ways to get the same info. this will get the RAM reported by the CIM_ComputerSystem class. that number is reported in bytes, so dividing by `1GB` gives that number in GB. [*grin*]

```
$Ram_GB = [math]::Round((Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_ComputerSystem).TotalPhysicalMemory / 1GB, 2)

$Ram_GB
```

output = `8` on my system.

Comment: I already did this as workaround, but there are either items I need to parse in english besides ``systeminfo``.

Comment: if the items are available thru CIM/WMI, then i would use that since it gives you data instead of strings. if you need to set the language of some report ... then i suspect you will need to set the language for the OS to that target language - and likely will need to restart the system to make it take effect.

Answer (score 0):

For me a workaround to replace systeminfo.exe (which delivers the language specific output) was the usage of the following command:

```
powershell -Command gcim CIM_ComputerSystem -Property *
```

Which delivers something like:

```
AdminPasswordStatus         : 3
BootupState                 : Normal boot
ChassisBootupState          : 3
KeyboardPasswordStatus      : 3
PowerOnPasswordStatus       : 3
PowerSupplyState            : 3
PowerState                  : 0
FrontPanelResetStatus       : 3
ThermalState                : 3
Status                      : OK
Name                        : MYPC
PowerManagementCapabilities :
PowerManagementSupported    :
Caption                     : MYPCPW
Description                 : AT/AT COMPATIBLE
InstallDate                 :
CreationClassName           : Win32_ComputerSystem
NameFormat                  :
PrimaryOwnerContact         :
PrimaryOwnerName            : 
Roles                       : {LM_Workstation, LM_Server, NT}
InitialLoadInfo             :
LastLoadInfo                :
ResetCapability             : 1
AutomaticManagedPagefile    : True
AutomaticResetBootOption    : True
AutomaticResetCapability    : True
BootOptionOnLimit           :
BootOptionOnWatchDog        :
BootROMSupported            : True
BootStatus                  : {0, 0, 0, 0...}
ChassisSKUNumber            : Notebook
CurrentTimeZone             : 120
DaylightInEffect            : True
DNSHostName                 : MYPCPW
Domain                      : 
DomainRole                  : 1
EnableDaylightSavingsTime   : True
HypervisorPresent           : False
InfraredSupported           : False
Manufacturer                : Dell Inc.
Model                       : Precision 5530
NetworkServerModeEnabled    : True
NumberOfLogicalProcessors   : 12
NumberOfProcessors          : 1
OEMLogoBitmap               :
OEMStringArray              : {Dell System, 1[087D], 3[1.0], 12[www.dell.com]...}
PartOfDomain                : True
PauseAfterReset             : -1
PCSystemType                : 2
PCSystemTypeEx              : 2
ResetCount                  : -1
ResetLimit                  : -1
SupportContactDescription   :
SystemFamily                : Precision
SystemSKUNumber             : 087D
SystemStartupDelay          :
SystemStartupOptions        :
SystemStartupSetting        :
SystemType                  : x64-based PC
TotalPhysicalMemory         : 34079059968
UserName                    : uidg1234
WakeUpType                  : 6
Workgroup                   :
PSComputerName              :
CimClass                    : root/cimv2:Win32_ComputerSystem
CimInstanceProperties       : {Caption, Description, InstallDate, Name...}
CimSystemProperties         : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties
```

Additional Information might be reached via:

```
powershell -Command gcim CIM_Chip -Property *
powershell -Command gcim WIN32_Bios -Property *
```